# Rich Text Editor for iPad

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, uiwebview, tinymce

I am developing an iPad app that contains a Rich Text Editor. I did some research and found an excellent tool called TinyMCE. I am trying to integrate TinyMCE in my app, has anybody succeeded in integrating the same.